# NGINX point subdomain to dyanimc directory

Tags: nginx, subdomain, rules

Suppose I have a domain **example.com** and it is located in *www/wwwroot/example*. I also have created a subdomain **api.example.com** by creating a CNAME **api** pointing to **example.com**. For the usage purposes, I have created a directory named **api** which is located on *www/wwwroot/api* which is certainly not in the root direcory of my domain.

I will host different independent project's API codes in the API directory (*www/wwwroot/api*).

Suppose I have a project named **DemoProject** and I have created a direcorty along with the necessary API codes inside the directory (www/wwwroot/api/DemoProject).

Now what I want is if I call **api.example.com/DemoProject** it should point to the directory  *www/wwwroot/api/DemoProject*. How can I do it in NGINX?

Here I need some rules so that I can access any directory inside *www/wwwroot/api* whenever I call api.example.com/DirectoryName matching with the directory name.

Like:

- **api.example.com/Google** should point to *www/wwwroot/api/Google*
- **api.example.com/Facebook** should point to *www/wwwroot/api/Facebook*
- **api.example.com/Netflix** should point to *www/wwwroot/api/Netflix*

Here is my current example.com domain's NGNIX config file

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com api.example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
    root /www/wwwroot/panel_ssl_site;

    #SSL-START SSL related configuration, do NOT delete or modify the next line of commented-out 404 rules
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_START
    if ($server_port !~ 443){
        rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_END
    ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;


    #SSL-END
    #referenced redirect rule, if commented, the configured redirect rule will be invalid
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/redirect/example.com/*.conf;

    #ERROR-PAGE-START  Error page configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #error_page 502 /502.html;
    #ERROR-PAGE-END

    #PHP-INFO-START  PHP reference configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    #SECURITY-START Hotlink protection configuration
    location ~ .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        access_log off;
        valid_referers example.com;
        if ($invalid_referer){
           return 404;
        }
    }
    #SECURITY-END
    include enable-php-00.conf;
    #PHP-INFO-END

    #REWRITE-START URL rewrite rule reference, any modification will invalidate the rewrite rules set by the panel
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/example.com.conf;
    #REWRITE-END

    # Forbidden files or directories
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
    {
        return 404;
    }

    # Directory verification related settings for one-click application for SSL certificate
    location ~ \.well-known{
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log off; 
    }
    access_log  /www/wwwlogs/example.com.log;
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/example.com.error.log;
}
```

I am very very new to the administritive task. I am doing it for few of my personal projects. I am having difficulties to face this. I apologize in advance if this is a simple problem. Also thanks in advance.

## Edit

In the config, in the line

```
server_name example.com api.example.com;
```

I have both domain and subdomain because I have enabled redirection. If someone calls only api.example.com then it will be redirected to example.com.

Comment: `example.com` and `api.example.com` should each have their own `server` blocks.

Comment: It is more efficient and cleaner to have a separate `server` block for the redirect.